# Copying from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook called Sheeter Production Report that an operator fills out. Normally they click on the "End of Shift" button and it saves the workbook with the shift and date then reopens the blank Sheeter Production Report.

Sometimes I need to transfer data between the workbooks so I have it transfer the data to the reopened workbook.

Code to transfer the data.

```vb
Sub Transfer_1()

Range("G5").MergeArea.Copy
Workbooks("Sheeter Production Report").Worksheets("Production Report").Range("G5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("G7").MergeArea.Copy
Workbooks("Sheeter Production Report").Worksheets("Production Report").Range("G7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H5").MergeArea.Copy
Workbooks("Sheeter Production Report").Worksheets("Production Report").Range("H5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("I5").MergeArea.Copy
Workbooks("Sheeter Production Report").Worksheets("Production Report").Range("I5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("K5").MergeArea.Copy
Workbooks("Sheeter Production Report").Worksheets("Production Report").Range("K5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("L5").MergeArea.Copy
Workbooks("Sheeter Production Report").Worksheets("Production Report").Range("L5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("M5").MergeArea.Copy
Workbooks("Sheeter Production Report").Worksheets("Production Report").Range("M5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("N5").MergeArea.Copy
Workbooks("Sheeter Production Report").Worksheets("Production Report").Range("N5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("Q5").MergeArea.Copy
Workbooks("Sheeter Production Report").Worksheets("Production Report").Range("Q5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("AB5").MergeArea.Copy
Workbooks("Sheeter Production Report").Worksheets("Production Report").Range("R5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("S5").MergeArea.Copy
Range("R5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("AC5").Copy
Workbooks("Sheeter Production Report").Worksheets("Production Report").Range("X2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I get

> Run-time error "9" Subscript out of range.

It renames the workbook and opens the Sheeter Production Report workbook but when it goes to copy and paste the data it kicks out the error on

```
Workbooks("Sheeter Production Report").Worksheets("Production Report").Range("G5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I created a blank workbook called Book1/Sheet1 and swapped that out with Sheeter Production Report/Production Report in the first line and it will transfer when using F5. But it kicks out the error again when it goes to the next line. Last week it was working.

Comment: I'm not what's going on here, but excel tends to hate copy/paste with merged cells. You might try `Range().value = Range().value`. Is the copy section definitely merged? Is the destination section merged or not.

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to add the file extension (`.xlsx`, `.xlsm`, ...) when you call `Workbooks` with a workbook name. In any case, you should always check your objects exist before using them like in any other programming language.

Comment: When you have opened the SPR workbook, its active sheet has become the application's active sheet (`ActiveSheet`) and `Range("G5").MergeArea` is a reference in it.

Comment: When you have opened the SPR workbook, its active sheet has become the application's active sheet (`ActiveSheet`) and `Range("G5").MergeArea` is a reference in it. Where exactly is this code located and how do you run it (another button)? Where is (should be) the unqualified range located? In `SPR_20230124.xlsm` or in `SPR.xlsm`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) I'm not saying that this post contains the literal answer to your question, but there is a clear replacement of `source.Copy, Destination.Paste` into `Destination.Value = Source.Value`, which I believe is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Transfer_1()
    
    Dim ws_Prod_Rpt As Worksheet
    Dim ws_Dest_Sht As Worksheet
    Dim RG As Range
    Dim AddressList
    Dim I As Long
    
    Set ws_Dest_Sht = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Dest_Worksheet")
    Set ws_Prod_Rpt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Production Report")
    
    AddressList = Array("G5", "G7", "H5", "I5", "K5", _
                        "L5", "M5", "N5", "Q5", "AB5", _
                        "S5", "R5", "AC5")
    
    With ws_Prod_Rpt
        For I = 0 To UBound(AddressList)
            Debug.Print I & " - " & AddressList(I)
            Set RG = .Range(AddressList(I)).MergeArea
            Debug.Print RG.Address
            ws_Dest_Sht.Range(AddressList(I)) = RG.Value
        Next I
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I think the `With` May be superfluous, however I had added it in when I thought it was more complicated.
Let me know if you run into issues.